# Angular mat-pagination onClick next page appears black border

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using mat paginator, when i am changing pages, i am getting

[image]

How can i fix it? Mb i missed some module?
my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How paginator looks:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 15, 30]" [pageSize]="5" [length]="totalElements"
               (page)="nextPage($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Do you have any custom styles?
If so, it may cause a collision of styles, and that's why you see the border.

Comment: I don't have custom styles. Only boostrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap may cause a collision of styles, try this in your `styles.css`:

```
button:focus, 
button:active:focus, 
button.active:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  outline-style: none !important;
}
```